# Getting all information from duplicate rows

Tags: sql

I need to get duplicates (with same rID and mID) from table 'Rating' (https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/moviedata.html). I thought it would be easy to just use this code:

```
SELECT 
     rating.rid, rating.mid
FROM 
     rating 
GROUP BY
     rating.rid, rating.mid
HAVING
     COUNT(*) > 1
```

it gave me result:

```
rID mID
201 101
203 108
```

not bad but I need **ALL** duplicate rows with this results because although they have same *rID* and *mID* columns, *stars* and *ratingdate* columns are different (I need them to solve the next part of the exercise). I have done it almost with this code:

```
SELECT first.rid, first.mid, first.stars
FROM rating AS first
                    INNER JOIN 
                                (SELECT 
                                    rating.rid, rating.mid, stars, COUNT(*)
                                FROM 
                                    rating  
                                GROUP BY
                                    rating.rid, rating.mid
                                HAVING
                                    COUNT(*) > 1) AS second
                                ON first.rid = second.rid
```

Output:

```
rID  mID stars
201  101   2
201  101   4
203  103   2
203  108   4
203  108   2
```

but as you see it threw me out one bad row:

```
rID  mID stars
203  103   2
```

My question is how to get this result:

```
rID  mID stars
201  101   2
201  101   4
203  108   4
203  108   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more condition in the ON clause of your query, because you define duplicates when the have both `rid` and `mid` equal:

```
SELECT first.rid, first.mid, first.stars
FROM rating AS first INNER JOIN (
  SELECT rid, mid
  FROM rating  
  GROUP BY rid, mid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS second 
ON first.rid = second.rid AND first.mid = second.mid
```

I simplified the subquery, by removing unnecessary columns in the select statement.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain me more deeply why you have used this second condition? Because so far I thought we use ON clause to just 'connect' two or more tables. To be honest I don't know what really happen when we use ON clause and I think example above is good to say something a bit about this.

Comment: The subquery returns the duplicate rids and mids. So you join the rows of the table to these pairs. If the row does not match both the rid and the mid then it does not belong to that subquery so it has no duplicate and it is rejected. But if it matches both on rid and mid this means that it is one of the rows tah has a duplicate so it is included in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions can help:

```
SELECT rId, mId, stars
FROM (SELECT rId, mId, stars
           , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rId, mId) AS c
      FROM rating)
WHERE c > 1
ORDER BY rId, mId
```